# Complex relationships with Eloquent/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Same story as many other questions on this site: I've banged my head into the wall for hours on end trying to figure out these relationships.

I have 3 models where the relationship should work like this:

**Model: User**
User can belong to many schools.
User belongs to one “Role” separately on each school.
User can be activated/deactivated separately on each school.

**Model: School**.
School can belong to many users

**Model: Role**.
Roles would be “Standard” or “Administrator”.

I have a pivot table that connects users and schools. 
On the pivot table, I've also experimented with adding 'role_id' and 'is_activated' columns - which I doubt is the correct way about doing this?

---

I want to access data like this:

**User**
Get schools belonging to the user.
Get role for current school.
Get activated/deactivated status for current school.

**School**
Get all users belonging to the school.
Get role for each user.
Get activated/deactived status for each user.

---

I would've solved this if users could only belong to one school each, but since the same user can belong to several schools it got too complicated for me.

What kind of relationships should I apply on each model?

I would very much appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a `many-to-many` relationship between `user` and `school`. This would require a pivot table between them to store the ids of the two models. At the end your relationship from a user point of view will end up being:

```
public function schools() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\School', 'pivot_table', 'user_id', 'school_id');
}
```

You can have a look at [laravel docs on Many-to-Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: Thanks, but I already have a pivot table for the many-to-many relationships between users and schools. 

My problem is figuring out the relationship with roles. 
User can for example have the role "Administrator" on school #1 and the role "Standard" on school #2. I also need to figure out how to see if user is activated/deactived on each school. I'm trying to cram these two things into the same pivot table you mention, but I think I'm om the wrong path.

Comment: @JayMellow, the same applies as well. You need an extra column perhaps on the pivot between user and school for role_id. Since a user will only ever have a link to one school (a distinct validation between user_id and school_id), you can add the role_id to the pivot table. this helps you link the role the User has for that particular School.

Comment: Missed the second question @JayMellow, since the activated_deactivated indicator is related to the School and User directly, i would also put it on the pivot table as well.

Comment: Thanks Leo. Is there a way for me to access the users role like this? user->role->type, based on customer relation somehow? Or do i have to rely on 'wherePivot('customer_id', 3)' etc?

Comment: I solved my last question like this:
$this->getUser()->roles()->wherePivot('school_id', $school_id)->first()->name
Dont know if there is a better way? It works at least.

Comment: Solved access to is_activated status for user like this:
$this->getUser()->roles()->wherePivot('school_id', $school_id)->withPivot('is_activated')->first()->pivot->is_activcated


It's a lengthy one, but it'll have to do for now. If you dont see a better way?

Comment: Hi @JayMellow, the solutions you have used are fine. I have tried that out and it works since within your relationship you are explicitly specifying the pivot relationship. If there is a better solution i's sure the guys will suggest in the future. Cheers